# Format date in reactive form

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Currently it displays 1/4/2022 , it should display 01/04/2022(it should be on this format) , the question is , is there a way we can achieve this format using the reactive forms based on my sample Model form below ? Thanks.

How do we format it from here       transactionStartDate: [this.model.transactionStartDate || new Date()],
? is a date fns tool required?

[image]

#html code

```
 <mat-form-field appearance="fill" class="transaction-control-filter" fxFlex="100">
                <mat-label class="transaction-detail-header-label">Transaction Start Date</mat-label>
                <input matInput [matDatepicker]="pickerStart" formControlName="transactionStartDate">
                <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="pickerStart"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
                <mat-datepicker #pickerStart class="transaction-detail-header-label"></mat-datepicker>
            </mat-form-field>
```

#ts code

```
private modelForm(): FormGroup {
      transactionStartDate: [this.model.transactionStartDate || new Date()],
    });
  }
```

Comment: You can refer to an [example](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview#datepicker-formats) from Angular Material doc

Comment: can we format it from here       transactionStartDate: [this.model.transactionStartDate || new Date()],
?

Answer (score 1):

According to [Angular Material](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview#customizing-the-parse-and-display-formats) you can use your own date formats, you can import the NativeDateModule or MomentDateModule (uses [Moment.Js](https://momentjs.com)).

Example:

in `app.module.ts`

```
//import needed modules
import { MatMomentDateModule, MomentDateAdapter } from '@angular/material-moment-adapter';
import { MAT_DATE_FORMATS, DateAdapter} from '@angular/material-moment-adapter';


//create your own formats
export const DateFormats = {
    parse: {
        dateInput: ['D/M/YYYY'] //D = Days, M = Months, Y = Years. you can change the input format
    },
    display: {
        dateInput: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
        monthYearLabel: 'MMM YYYY',
        dateA11yLabel: 'LL',
        monthYearA11yLabel: 'MMMM YYYY',
    }
};


//add it to your providers
..
providers: [
    ...,
    { provide: DateAdapter, useClass: MomentDateAdapter},
    { provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: DateFormats },
    ...
]
```

Of course you can modify the formats as you wish. The code above is not tested!
Make sure you have basic knowledge of [Moment.js formatting](https://momentjs.com/guides/#/parsing/strict-mode/)

Comment: is there a simple way to directly format it on  transactionStartDate: [this.model.transactionStartDate || new Date()],  from 1/4/2022  to 01/04/2022

Comment: @junrey using yeah, you can use `moment.js` for that. install it in your project and format your value however you wish

Comment: moment.js has been deprecated (https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/). Pick one from the listed alternatives..

Comment: @eol oh wow... thats actually sad, they did a great job tbh

Comment: Yeah. the only thing I did not like is its mutability - other than that great lib. :)

Comment: do you have some example ?